# How long must a sample be irradiated before all 59-Co atoms are converted to 60-Co?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

For the interaction,  n$^0$ + $^{59}$Co $\to$ $^{60}$Co

Comment: What do you know about the rate at which individual conversions occur? What can you deduce from that?

Comment: Unless the sample contains very few nuclei, that's probably never the case, because the 60Co starts decaying before the conversion is complete, and at the insane neutron flux that would be needed to convert almost instantaneously, it's likely (giant foam hand waving here!) that other reactions would occur in parallel which would bypass the "complete" conversion, again. I have no idea what a typical technologically sensible conversion efficiency would be, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, $^{59}$Co is the only stable isotope of Cobalt. Neutron irradiation results in formation of $^{60}$Co (plus an emitted gamma), which has a half life of 5.2 years. The decay is through beta decay, resulting in formation of stable $^{60}$Ni.

For nuclear physics cross section, a very useful website is the National Nuclear Data Center, hosted at BNL: [NNDC entry page](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/).  Selecting the Evaluated Nuclear Data File option pops up a page where you can select co-59, n (for neutrons), and sig (for cross sections sigma).  Then you get a huge long list of the evaluated data for about a gazillion possible neutron reactions with $^{59}$Co.  One of them is the $^{59}$Co (n,$\gamma$) $^{60}$Co reaction.  Pick those, and plot them to get the cross section versus neutron energy or ask for the text listing.

The thermal neutron cross section is on the order of 40 barns.  One barn is $10^{-24}$ cm$^2$. So, what is your neutron flux?  If I have 25 monolayers of Co (where I'm taking a monolayer as $10^{15}$ at/cm$^{2}$, we have a reaction probability of 1 in a million.

For your particular problem, you now have a set of equations, based on the neutron flux, of conversion from $^{59}$Co to $^{60}$Co from the neutron flux, and the decay of $^{60}$Co to $^{60}$Ni with the 5.2 year half life.

I'll note on a final reading of your question that it might really be about how long before all the $^{59}$Co has been made into $^{60}$Co, not how much $^{60}$Co is remaining.  That question is just a simple calculation from the initial number of $^{59}$Co atoms, the capture cross section, and the neutron flux.

---

EDIT - @CuriousOne raised a good point: what is happening to the $^{60}$Co under this flux of neutrons?  Well, as it turns out, a variety of things.  Sticking with thermal neutrons (~23meV or whatever is closest in the cross section tables) we have:

$^{60}$Co(n, tot) has $\sigma=3.4$ barns (total cross section for any interactions, including just scattering)

$^{60}$Co(n,$\gamma$)$^{61}$Co has $\sigma=2.08$ barns (so most of the cross section)

$^{60}$Co(n,p)$^{60}$Fe has $\sigma=9\times 10^{-12}$ barns (wow that is small!)

Many other possible reactions, almost all of which are at MeV neutron energies, not thermal.

So, under a neutron flux, the $^{60}$Co will transform into $^{61}$Co, although the cross section to do that is about 5% that of the $^{59}$Co to $^{60}$Co transformation.  $^{61}$Co has a half life of 1.65 hours, then decays to $^{61}$Ni which is a stable isotope. Then the $^{61}$Ni (n,$\gamma$) $^{62}$Ni cross section is about 2.6 barns. I could keep going, but will let the reader peruse the NNDC pages for their own edification.

Looks like you could have a lot of fun with the coupled equations to determine

Comment: Nice answer! How about competing reactions that convert 60Co by neutron capture to e.g. 61Co? Is there a limit to the equilibrium concentration? That would strongly depend on the neutron spectrum, right?